# Compile JasperReports with Gradle gets unsupported version error

Tags: gradle, ant, compilation, jasper-reports

Recently i implemented a new builder with gradle runs on jenkins. Our project contains jasper reports so i added below task to compile jasper reports with an ant task which is supplied by jasper reports api.

```
 task compileJasper {
  println "############# Compiling JasperReports in Projet $project.name ###################"
        def jasperSourceDir =sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs[0]
    def jasperTargetDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    def classPath = ant.path {
        fileset(dir: "JarLib/", includes: '**.jar')
    }
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'jrc', classname: 'net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask',
                                classpath: classPath)
        jasperTargetDir.mkdirs()
        jrc(srcdir: jasperSourceDir, destdir: jasperTargetDir) {
            classpath(path: classPath)
            include(name: '**/*.jrxml')
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine with compiling and works as expected but after deploying project to server, at runtime getting the following error.

> [8/3/17 14:38:53:340 EET] 000000f5 SystemOut     O ERROR [14:38:53,333
>   - WebContainer : 0] (RunReportBean.java:100) - ****Throwable java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version;
>   class=kybgeneldurum_1501049070032_205074, offset=6
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClass(JRClassLoader.java:337)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassFromBytes(JRClassLoader.java:238)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractJavaCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractJavaCompiler.java:104)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractCompiler.java:358)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:381)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:467)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.(BaseReportFiller.java:152)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.java:239)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:201)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:216)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:85)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
>           at tr.gov.uyap.fonk.report.engine.impl.jasper.JasperReportEngine.runReport(JasperReportEngine.java:95)

We use websphere 8.5 for runtime with java 1.6 . This is java -version output

> /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java -version java version
>   "1.6.0" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   pxa6460_26sr8fp2ifix-20141114_01(SR8
>   FP2+IV66608+IV66375+IX90155+IV66944)) IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.6.0
>   Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20141114_222464 (JIT enabled, AOT
>   enabled) J9VM - R26_Java626_SR8_20141114_1023_B222464 JIT  -
>   r11.b07_20141003_74578.01 GC   -
>   R26_Java626_SR8_20141114_1023_B222464_CMPRSS J9CL - 20141114_222464)
>   JCL  - 20141005_01

At first time i got the error gradle configured to run with java 1.7.0_51 so i changed gradle java to "java 1.6.03" but nothing changed. Any idea ?

Comment: With a typical workflow, the developer writing the report is also responsible for compiling the report (during development to preview and verify that the report functions correctly). There's usually no need to compile reports using a separate process--unless the reports are machine generated.

Comment: We do not commit binary folders to code repository. So we have to compile report files during jenkins build process

Comment: @mfidan I just want to know what kind of deployment process you are using to deploy reports to jasper server.If any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I printed all ant properties with the following code in the ant block.

```
ant {
    for (o in properties)
     println o
     ...
     ..
     .
}
```

I see that gradle somehow use system default java as java.endoresed.dir property although i set the `org.gradle.java.home` value to 1.6 in the `gradle.properties` file.

> java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/endorsed

I ended up the issue with changing the system java version to 1.6.
This maybe a gradle bug.